# Would it be ok if i had only 1 main woocommerce category?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Would it be fine if i had 1 main product category in woocommerce with lots of child categories? I'm talking about thousands products in this 1 main category with many subcategories.

Is this alright, or not recommended? 
What about speed of the page, will it affect it in any way by doing this?

Comment: The way you phrase this is way too broad. Having only 1 category should not be a problem. Having many products can be a problem. But it is solvable by using proper code. I think the best course for you would be to test this on a local site

Comment: What would be the point? Just use the subcategories as categories.

Comment: The reason is because the current domain has this setup, and would be difficult to change how it shows the categories in menu, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good hosting and the site is optimized( cache plugin, optimized images, etc. ) then there will be no problems with any styles of categories.

Check this: [Is your WooCommerce site slow](https://woocommerce.com/posts/woocommerce-site-slow-fixes/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the speed is a relevant factor here. In my experience a good categorization is actually good for 2 factors, one related to the other:

- **User Experience**: with the right mix of categories and subcategories you can definitely help the users through the purchase funnel and optimize your overall CTR. Of course you shouldn't even over-categorize it.
- **Search Engine Optimization**: with a good navigation tree, the overall User Experience will improve your website usability, affecting your website ranking in a positive way.

Lately I personally don't get the point to have just one category. 
Hope this helps.